# Read certificates available in Windows keystore without password

Tags: java, keystore, microsoft-key-storage-provider

I need to retrieve the list of certificates available in the windows keystore without the user having to enter his password in each certificate manager.

A simple example: when you want to sign a PDF document with Adobe Reader, Adobe Reader first displays the list of certificates available in the keystore, the user chooses the certificate he wants to sign with, and then the certificate manager asks the user for his password.

```
 keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", "SunMSCAPI");
 keyStore.load(null, null);
```

This is the code I wrote in Java to read the certificates available in the Windows keystore.

Read the available certificates, and that it is when using a certificate that the certificate manager asks for the password.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is. You have not asked any question. Please [edit] your post to include a question you want to ask.

Comment: That would be a security breach, which would make the resulting digital signature legally worthless. The idea is that the user has taken a positive step to sign the document. If the computer did it automatically, it's not the same thing.